# Updating logging sheet from another sheet doesn't work after inserting code offset

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to log the data, formulas and times of cell edits from one sheet into a logging sheet. The problem I am having is that it only seems to record changes made in the logging sheet. This has started happening since I added the row offset functionality

Below is the code for my onedit and getting the next available cell to record the information.

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Exam");
  var activeRange = activeSheet.getActiveRange();
  var activeCell = activeRange.getA1Notation();
  var cellValue = activeRange.getValue();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula();
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Logging"); 

  if(activeSheet.getName() != targetSheet.getName()) {

    //Set Values entered in Curret Sheet in Logging sheet for first row
    if(targetSheet.getRange("B4").getValue() == "") {
      targetSheet.getRange("B4").setValue(activeSheet.getName());
      targetSheet.getRange("C4").setValue(activeCell);
      targetSheet.getRange("D4").setValue((new Date().toTimeString()));
      targetSheet.getRange("F4").setValue(cellValue);
      targetSheet.getRange("G4").setValue(formula);
    }
    else {
      //Set Values entered in Curret Sheet in Logging sheet for every other row
      var nextEmptyRow = getNextEmptyRow(); //Get next available row that we can log to.
      targetSheet.getRange("B" + nextEmptyRow).setValue(activeSheet.getName());
      targetSheet.getRange("C" + nextEmptyRow).setValue(activeCell);
      targetSheet.getRange("D" + nextEmptyRow).setValue((new Date().toTimeString()));
      targetSheet.getRange("F" + nextEmptyRow).setValue(cellValue);
      targetSheet.getRange("G" + nextEmptyRow).setValue(formula);
    }
  }
  //onCellExit(event,activeSheet,activeCell,targetSheet); //Record the values in the logging sheet that were entered in the cell
};

//Get next available row that we can log to.
function getNextEmptyRow() {
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ran = spr.getRange('B:B');
  var arr = [];
  for (var i= ran.getLastRow(); i>0; i--){
    if(ran.getCell(i,1).getValue()){
      break;
    }
  }
  return (Number(i+1));
}
```

The second question I have is how do I record the event that occurred in the cell such as value changed or delete range, or update value etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do all that, with the code below.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();  
  if(sName !== "Logging") {
    var value;
    var mA1 = e.range.getA1Notation().split(":")[0];
    var time = new Date().toTimeString();    
    if(typeof(e.value) == 'string') {
      var aCell = e.source.getRange(mA1);
      value = aCell.getValue();
      var form = "'" + aCell.getFormula();
    } else {
      value = e.value;      
    }
    var data = [sName, mA1, time, value, form];
    e.source.getSheetByName("Logging").appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

### Explained

The `onEdit` will only work, if the active sheet isn't named `Logging`. Next is to gather the wanted info and append it to the logger sheet. The range of the active cell needs to be a cell reference (`A1`). A formula, with other references, will mix up the `A1Notation`. Therefore the `split(":")[0]` will take the first active cell reference (if you add a `=` or `+`) as range. If the cell happens to have a formula, then the value is obtained through the `e.source` else through the `e.value`. The formula is also obtained through the `e.source` and stringified.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Logger Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdG9WbEN2eW0zR2VFQnV6dXVIVzVVSVE&usp=sharing)**