# Change logs for Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

We've got a large shared spreadsheet which is a chart showing user permissions. It's writable by several people. Although Google Drive allows you to roll back the changes simply its interface isn't really that great for at a checking changes.

Is there a way you can automatically create a sheet called 'changes' or 'change log', etc., and have all changes listed in there? [There is something like this using Excel macros](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/704212-log-creation-excel-changes-sheet.html).

Is it possible in Google Spreadsheets either natively / with an app or with a custom script?

I know I could also export as a CSV and compare versions with Git but that's a long-winded approach.

Comment: Why don't you look at this answer I gave, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58308/29140, on a very similar question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating logging sheet from another sheet doesn't work after inserting code offset](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58297/updating-logging-sheet-from-another-sheet-doesnt-work-after-inserting-code-offs)

Comment: I don't believe that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Yes, it's possible. To do that you will require to use the Edit or Change Google Sheets events of [Google Apps Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/).

## Extended answer

You can find a code example in the [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58308/88163) from Jacob Jan Tuinstra to [Updating logging sheet from another sheet doesn't work after inserting code offset](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58297/updating-logging-sheet-from-another-sheet-doesnt-work-after-inserting-code-offs/58308#58308)

## References

- [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
- [Events Objects - Guides - Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)